# Connector for a certain type of lead-acid battery

Tags: batteries, connector, lead-acid

I need to connect some lead-acid batteries together, to form a bank. A fair amount of current will be drawn from them.

However, I haven't seen the terminals used in those batteries before. What should I use to form a solid connection between them?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called spade connectors.

[image: Spade connector]

They're often available with plastic covers to make them a little bit safer against someone dropping a spanner on the terminals. Here's some with a useful banana plug lead on:

[image: Lead acid battery lead]

Available from [Gliders Distribution](http://www.gliders.uk.com/prodinfo.asp?number=G3055)